# Besides "all of them" as an answer, what type of applications (be specific) have had true success with unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

- What type of applications did you use this TDD, unit testing approaching (web app, compiler, rails, etc?).
- What language was your application written in?
- Did you use a preexisting unit testing frameworking like junit or nunit or did you you rollo your own.
- Did you use automatically code generate your test cases or was most of the work through manual creation?
- Did you integrate your unit tests with an automatic build program like cruise control or something similar?
- Would you consider your tests very fine grained, low level or were they very high level tests ("Test the Entire Page").

Comment: Rest assured "all of them" is not the answer.

Comment: This isn't a question with a "right" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them.

(Sorry, this just has to be said)

Answer (score 1):

[#67299](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299/is-unit-testing-worth-the-effort)

[#286587](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286587/are-you-really-using-unit-tests)

[#301693](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301693/why-didnt-unit-testing-work-out-for-your-project)

Answer (score 0):

I have unit tested Rails web apps and standalone Ruby apps with Rspec and Test:Unit. Real tests cannot be generated, perhaps stubbed out at best. I did use cruisecontrol, but found it a bit cumbersome to use as an actual integration tool. It is useful as a badge of pride between devs, ensuring vigilance in passing the test suite before you commit your code.
My unit tests tend to be pretty low level, as far as I know functional tests are for high level stuff.

And yes, I have never regretted writing unit tests for my code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would say applications where unit testing was done from an early stage of the process.  Bolting it on to an existing zillion line application is not nearly as effective as doing it from the outset.

It also helps if there's good support in the language.  Java and .NET both have excellent XUnit frameworks -- C++ has a bit more of a hard time.