# How do you persuade others to write unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing

I've been test-infected for a long time now, but it would seem the majority of developers I work with either have never tried it or dismiss it for one reason or another, with arguments typically being that it adds overhead to development or they don't need to bother.

What bothers me most about this is that when I come along to make changes to their code, I have a hard time getting it under test as I have to apply refactorings to make it testable and sometimes end up having to do *a lot* of work just so that I can test the code I'm about to write.

What I want to know is, what arguments would you use to persuade other developers to start writing unit tests? Most developers I've introduced to it take to it quite well, see the benefits and continue to use it.  This always seems to be the *good* developers though,  who are already interested in improving the quality of their code and hence can see how unit testing does this.

How do persuade the rest of the motley crew? I'm not looking for a list of testing benefits as *I* already know what these are, but what techniques you have used or would use to get other people on board.  Tips on how to persuade management to take an active role are appreciated as well

Comment: Very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299/is-unit-testing-worth-the-effort

Comment: test-infected: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/testinfected/testing.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's more than one side to that question, I guess. I find that actually convincing developers to starting using tests is not that hard, because the list of advantages of using testing often speaks for itself. When that said, it is quite a barrier to actually get going and I find that the learning curve often is a bit steep – especially for novice coders. Throwing testing frameworks, TDD test-first mentality, and mocking framework at someone who's not yet comfortable with neither C#, .Net or programming in general, could be just too much to handle.

I work as a consultant and therefore I often have to address the problem of implementing TDD in an organization. Luckily enough, when companies hire me it is often because of my expertise in certain areas, and therefore I might have a little advantage when it comes to getting people’s attention. Or maybe it's just that it's a bit easier to for me as an outsider to come in to a new team and say "Hi! I've tried TDD on other projects and I *know* that it works!" Or maybe it's my persuasiveness/stubbornness? :) Either way, I often don't find it very hard to convince devs to start writing tests. What I find hard though, is to teach them how to write good unit tests. And as you point out in your question; to stay on the righteous path.

But I have found one method that I think works pretty well when it comes to teaching unit testing. I've [blogged about it here](http://www.kjetilk.com/2008/12/effectively-teaching-test-first-make-it.html), but the essence is to sit down and do some pair-programming. And doing the pair programming I start out writing the unit test first. This way I show them a bit how the testing framework work, how I structure the tests and often some use of mocking. Unit tests should be simple, so all in all the test should be fairly easy to understand even for junior devs. The worst part to explain is often the mocking, but using easy-to-read mocking frameworks like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) helps a lot. Then when the test is written (and nothing compiles or passes) I hand over the keyboard to my fellow coder so that (s)he can implement the functionality. I simply tell her/him; "Make it go green!” Then we move on to the next test; I write the test, the 'soon-to-be-test-infected-dev' next to me writes the functionality.

Now, it's important to understand that at this point the dev(s) you are teaching are probably not yet convinced that this is the right way to code. The point where most devs seem to see the (green) light is when a test fails due to some code changes that they never thought would break any functionality. When the test that covers that functionality blows up, that's when you've got yourself a loyal TDD'er on your team. Or that's at least my experience, but as always; your mileage will vary :)

Comment: I like the "make it go green" idea.  I'm embarking on writing some training courses so may well include this approach in that to get them thinking about what they're doing rather than just copying what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: I'm seconding the suggestion of pair programming as a teaching method.  Pair programming is how I finally learned to do TDD the right way, and I haven't looked back since.  And it doesn't need to be at all formal.  Our scrum master asked if he could sit with me one day and did some back seat driving as I coded.  "Shouldn't you write that test first?  Why are you writing so many tests?  You seem to be writing a lot of code without a test around it."

Answer (score 7):

Quality speaks for itself.  If you're more successful than everyone else, that's all you need to say.

Answer (score 7):

Use a test-coverage tool. Make it very visible. That way everybody can easily see how much code in each area is passed, failed and untested.

Then you may be able to start a culture where "untested" is a sign of bad coding, "failed" is a sign of work in progress and "passed" is a sign of finished code.

This works best if you also do "test-first". Then "untested" becomes "you forgot step 1".

Of course you don't need 100% test coverage. But of one area has 1% coverage and another has 30%, you have a metric for which area is most likely to fail in production.

Answer (score 4):

**Lead by example**. If you can get evidence that there are less regression on unit tested code that elsewhere.

Getting QA and management buy-in so that your process mandates unit testing.

**Be ready to help** others to get started with unit testing: provide assistance, supply a framework so that they can start easily, run an introductory presentation.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to get used to the mantra "if it ain't tested, the work ain't done!"

**Edit:** To add some more meat to my facetious comment above, how can someone know if they're actually finished if they haven't tested their work?

Mind you, you will have a battle convincing others if time isn't allowed in the estimate for the testing of the devleoped code.

A one-to-one split for between effort for coding and that for testing seems to be a good number.

HTH

cheers,

Rob

Comment: I'll add that you have to preach by example as well and don't give up.

Answer (score 3):

Give compliments for one writes more test and produce good results and show the best one to others and ask them to produce the same or better result than this.

Answer (score 3):

People (and processes) don't change without one or more pain points. So you need to finjd the significant pain points and demonstrate how unit testing might help deal with them.

If you can't find any significant pain points, then unit testing may not add a lot of value to your current process.

As Steve Lott implies, delivering better results than the other team members will also help. But without the pain points, my experience is that people won't change.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways: convince the project manager that unit testing improves quality AND saves time overall, then have him make unit tests mandatory.

Or wait for a development crunch just before an important release date, where everyone has to work overtime and weekends to finish the last features and eliminate the last bugs, only to find they've just introduced more bugs. Then point out that with proper unit tests they wouldn't have to work like that.

Another situation where unit tests can be shown as indispensable is when a release was actually delivered and turns out to contain a serious bug due to last-minute changes.

Comment: My PM is fully onboard with unit testing as he's seen the benefits elsewhere, but it's persuading his boss that is a stumbling block, with too much lip service being paid but no commitment when it comes down allocating resources.

Comment: Also, we're required to do unit tests for SOX compliance but I'd rather be persuading developers it's a good idea *because* it's a good idea, not because it's something that's mandated with no good reasons to back it up

Comment: I've been in that same situation and made it work by giving a good example and pointing out situations where unit tests would have saved time and effort - it took quite some time, but eventually the developers were convinced.

Answer (score 1):

Probably reefnet_alex' answer helps you:
[Is Unit Testing worth the effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299/is-unit-testing-worth-the-effort#67500)

> I think it was Fowler who said:
>   "Imperfect tests, run frequently, are
>   much better than perfect tests that
>   are never written at all". I
>   interprate this as giving me
>   permission to write tests where I
>   think they'll be most useful even if
>   the rest of my code coverage is
>   woefully incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

If developers are seeing that the "successful" developers are writing unit tests, and they are still not doing it then I suggest unit tests should become part of the formal development life-cycle.

E.g. nothing can be checked in until a unit test is written and reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that your manager is on board with unit tests. If that's the case, then why isn't he (she) enforcing it? It isn't your job to get everybody else to follow along or to teach them and in fact, other developers will often resent you if you try to push it on them. In order to get your fellow developers to write unit tests, the manager has to emphasize it **strongly**. It might end up that part of that emphasis is education on unit test implementation which you might end up being the educator and that's great, but management of it is everything.

If you're in an environment where the group decides the style of implementation, then you have more of a say in how the group dynamic should be. If you are in that sort of environment and the group doesn't want to emphasize unit tests while you do, then maybe you're in the wrong group/company.

Comment: I think he's of the same opinion as me that **enforcing** it just builds resentment towards doing it.  I think it's doubly hard for me as I'm *just a contractor* and so struggle to get my opinions heard above the long standing permies.

Comment: I didn't realize you are a contractor. You're in a tough spot then. Even as a "permie" a person can only tell their boss the same thing X number of times. Once you've gotten your point across and made the benefits clear, you've done all you can. After that, it starts to sound like complaining.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that "evangelizing" or preaching rarely works.  As others have said, do it your way for your own code, make it known that you do it, but don't try to force others to do it.  If people ask about it be supportive and helpful.  Offer to do a few lunch-time seminars or informal dog and pony shows.  That will do a lot more than just complaining to your manager or the other developers that you have a hard time writing tests for code they wrote.

Slow and steady - it is not going to change overnight.

Once I realized that at one place where I worked the acceptance for peer reviews improved tremendously.  My group just did it and stopped trying to get others to do it.  Eventually people started asking s about how we got some of the success we did.  Then it was easier.

Answer (score 0):

We have a test framework which includes automated running of the test suite whenever anyone commits a change. If someone commits code that fails the tests, the whole team gets emailed with the errors.

This leads to introduced bugs being fixed pretty quickly.