# Automated Testing: ways to help and educate developers?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm a software test engineer embedded in a development team.  A large part of my job involves checking over the state of the project's automated tests (mainly unit/integration tests).

I'm not a short-sighted zealot who wants to force testing down everyone's throats, but I **do** want to help everyone to get the best out of the time they spend writing tests.  A lot of time is spent every week writing tests, so it is important to maximise the returns.

Right now, I do a few things to try and help.  Firstly, I always make myself available to talk about testability concerns.  E.g. try to identity a testing strategy, whether a particular design is testable and so forth.

In addition to explaining things to people and generally trying to help them out, I also review the finished code and the tests that they write (I have to sign off on stories, meaning that I am somewhat adversarial, too).

My current process is to sit down alone, work through their code and bookmark & comment all problem areas, places that things can be improved and the reason for it.  I then get the developer around to my PC and talk through all of the review points.  I then send them a decent write up so they have a record of it and they have easy reference.

I do **not** fix their code and tests for them, but I will add more test cases etc. if I spot gaps.  The reason I have decided not to fix up the tests for them is that it's too easy for developers to say "thanks" but to tune out.  My reasoning is that if they have to fix the problems I identified before I will sign off, it will lead to a better standard of testing on the project (i.e. more self-sufficient developer testing).

**My question is: When it comes to aiding the team, could I be doing anything better?  What approaches have you found that can be beneficial?**

I'd particularly like to hear from people holding similar positions who have faced the same challenges (e.g. helping improve the quality of the testing, demonstrating the value testing can bring in relevant situations and also striking a good balance between being supportive and adversarial.)

***edit**:
Thanks for the answers; all of them contained useful suggestions.  I marked the top one as the best answer as I guess it comes down to developer support, and pair programming is something I have not yet tried (short of a few impromptu 'here's how I'd do this' demonstrations after the tests had been written).  I'll give that a go with anyone who struggles with testing something :)  Cheers.

Comment: Your current process sound good to me: I don't see how to improve it.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581589/introducing-unit-testing-to-a-wary-team and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416231/how-do-you-persuade-others-to-write-unit-tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have certain people that tend to be weak at testing, then sit down with them, pair programming, sort of, and as they work on their code, you can help them see how they may test it.

After a while these people should get better at unit testing, and your work load on this should decrease.

The other thing is that everyone should be looking at tests. If I touch a function, make any change, then I should be checking on the tests to make certain they are complete.  If there is a problem I can discuss it with the developer.

You should also enlist the work of the team lead, as that is part of his responsibility, or should be, to ensure that everyone understands how to write tests well.

Comment: The pair programming suggestion is good.  I will definitely give that a try :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things I'd do:

1. Get them to run coverage and spot any missed areas of code and highlight how although they think they've got all the cases covered, they might not have.  I've done this with a few people and they always seem quite surprised at areas they've missed when they thought they'd written watertight tests
2. Start a "recipe" page on your local Wiki.  Every time someone comes up with a testing scenario that they can't figure out, or need your help with, stick it on the Wiki and make it easy to find.  Get other people to contribute as well
3. It sounds like you're already doing this anyway, but ensure when anyone has a testing related question, *make yourself available* even if it's to the detriment of your normal workload.  If you're passionate about it, it should inspire those who are interested to do the right thing too.

When I'm introducing someone to testing (or a new testing technique), I'll often spend alot of my time randomly wandering over to their workstation just to see how they're getting on and nudge them in the right direction.  This can be fitted in quite nicely when going for tea/smoke breaks or when you're doing a build.  I've had quite good feedback about this but YMMV.

Comment: All good suggestions, but I'm doing them already :)  

Perhaps I will try and overhaul the wiki to focus on the process of writing tests as opposed to just random tips.  A more structured focus may be better than a cookbook approach.

I'll give the wandering aspect a try, too. 

Cheers.

Comment: Mark- I'd go for structured *and* cookbook.  Structured for the general unit test theory and the cookbook for recipes that are specific for your company

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the team, I wonder if it may make sense after an initial review of the code, to pull someone else to be another set of eyes that can look through what changes you'd propose and act as a way to show that this isn't just your opinion on it.  This could work as a way to highlight where there may be some tension in terms of what changes you'd like to see that a developer may reply, "Oh, that'll take weeks and likely isn't worth it..." or something similar if what you'd like to change isn't that simple.

In a similar vein, how does most of the team view testing?  Are there leaders or those highly respected that have a positive view on it and help foster a positive attitude towards it?  Is there general documentation about the testing guidelines that may help those new to the team to get up to speed quickly?  These are just a few other areas I'd examine since sometimes tests can be a great thing and sometimes they can be a pain.  Much like the glass that is half-empty or half-full depending on how you want to see it.

Not that I've had the same position, but as someone that has been a developer for a while, this is just what I'd like to see to help make testing be a good thing, as Martha Stewart would say.

Comment: The mediator idea is good, but it's hard to take other people's time away from their own work unless something really needs sorted out :(

I always make my feedback available to the leads (who are well respect) as well, so they can act as arbitrators if any significant disagreements occur.  

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Nice to hear there are options for resolving the cases where problems may arise.  The idea behind the mediator is also on trying to enforce coding standards and get to a homogenous code base where one isn't going to easily know who wrote what part since it all looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

One way to gently ease the team into getting tests started is to initiate the practice of writing tests when bugs are being fixed. So when a bug comes in, the first thing to do is write a test that will fail because the of the bug, fix the bug and then get the test to pass.

This approach can also be done when code gets modified internally (no public API changes) - write tests to cover the area being modified to ensure that it doesn't get broken by the code changes. Writing tests this way is a lot less work and clearly demonstrates the benefits once the developer catches their first regression bug.