# Is Unit Testing worth the effort, in a large and old (5yr) codebase?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I've just joined a team which has been working in a main-always mode for the last 5 yrs (java, maven based project). Consequently plans to leverage unit testing have always been in the pipeline, never materialising (so far). A Great dev team has ensured that code quality is generally good, and there aren't structural code issues, but there's just no culture of writing jnuit tests. But I, having seen the benefits of unit testing, am a lone warrior here pushing for adoption of auto-testing.

The team layout is such that a separate testing team does manual testing of functionality before rolling out the code, and a change management team is a checkgate for change approvals and builds (no continuous integration either, so far).

Following are the hurdles: Because the code base is huge,and some of the original developers have left the team, any additional unit tests may be too little, too late.
Add to it that I may be the only one pushing for unit testing. Though my manager has been supportive of the idea, he doesnt want the change team to be bogged down by additional time required for the tests to run.

I'm of the opinion that a stand-alone CI tool can be used to start off with, and the change team must alter their scripts to skip tests, as and when they are added.

What would you do in my shoes?

P.S.: I'm aware of a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299/is-unit-testing-worth-the-effort) , but in this one, the aim is to convince the different stakeholders and the best path to takel; not a technology comparison.

Comment: I just discovered that there is a separate mini-project with only test cases in it. These are a very small number of tests, and presumably a part of an ancient effort to cross testing out of the pending list. 
Besides, they offer no code guarantee, because they dont run everytime the code is compiled. 
Fresh test writing efforts are not helped by the fact that the code has not been written with automated tests in mind - parts have no scope to insert test/mock objects, and a large mock framework may need to be evoloved. But I suppose the consensus so far is to persist with writing new tests?

Comment: A common error is thinking of unit testing as *additional* testing.  Unit testing *replaces* (repetitive) manual testing.  You have to find the bugs somehow; what are the most efficient methods?  If you don't use unit testing, what will you do instead?  Usually the answer is:  a full build after every change, and step through by hand:  hand-crafted artisanal testing.  It is expensive, slow, boring, and subject to human error.  As a note, if you do want to single-step through code, a unit test that calls it with exactly the conditions of interest is a great place to do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you have a pretty good handle on the situation.

Two things:

1. Don't expect to be able to fully unit test a 5 year old project. Assuming 5 developers working for 5 years, you're in the neighborhood of 50,000 programmer-hours. Assuming that tests take as much time to write as code, you'd be doing pretty good to get 2-3% coverage in a year.
2. So: Test new code, and write tests for modifications of older code. Get time / take time to set up CI of some kind. Gradually, you'll build up a nice battery of tests.

Since you're apparently not drowning in bugs, start slow, gain momentum.

Comment: "Assuming that tests take as much time to write as code"
The main reason the team never wrote code was because of the notion that they'd rather spend that time writing new code. And that's the notion I need to battle.
I could show them the spreadsheets, the statistics on how test writing actually saves long run time, but nobody's interested in the long run.
Any suggestions how to persuade these devs to start writing unit tests NOW?

Comment: Yes, lead by example.  Mandating the writing of tests can work on a new team (I've done it, and been thanked later by people who took the habit with them to other teams), but on an existing team you'll likely only make them NOT want to test even more.   

So... start writing them yourself.  Focus on bugs (write the failing test, THEN fix the bug) and on new code, especially any tricky code.  The first time your suite catches a regression bug will be the moment you start making converts.

Comment: @Varun - the best way to get someone test infected is to have a unit test save their ass a few times. The only way that can happen is if they actually write some tests :P  A lot of developers unfamiliar with unit testing don't do it because they just don't know what to do. Give them a few examples of what good tests looks like, and how easy they are to write, and they will come around.

Comment: We got our first compilation error in the code base today. I see a BIG opportunity. A CI tool at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

It would be worth writing tests to test specific functionality that you are working on and you want to remain stable.

With a large existing application that has no test coverage at the moment, you wouldn't want to sit down and write tests all in one go in order to get 100% unit test coverage and you never will.  You'd just single out specific functionality for testing.  I don't think there's such a thing as too little or too late; unit tests for only a tiny bit of very important functionality is better than none at all, and some unit tests now are better than no unit tests ever.

Comment: Problem is, I want the rest of the team to start writing tests too, and possibly to see its value. Trying to find the path of least resistance.

Comment: You could lead by example, start off by writing a few tests and then, as they help track down regressions, boast about the time they've saved you.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is advantageous even in an old project, for example, by establishing unit tests, you can be sure that the problem is not in existing code but in new code (even if you have a QA process, bugs do still get through on occassion). Additionally, they prevent changes to old code from introducing subtle differences in behavior. Also, unit tests document the intended behavior of the huge codebase.

Now, adopting large changes are never easy. The first and most straightforward thing is to mandate unit testing of all new code, so that the effort and workload of unit testing the old codebase doesn't continue to pile up. Then, the second part is to take the initiative, and create some unit tests for the old code. If you do that, then you should be able to convince other members of your team to help with the effort in creating unit tests for existing code. If necessary, come up with fun incentives, like promising a pizza party for the team that creates the largest number of unit tests for the existing code base.

Also, remind your teammates that this isn't something where they need to drop everything that they are doing... if they only create one unit test for an existing component each day on top of their other work, then eventually you will get a unit test for all the existing components in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, unit tests or any other tests for that matter (except for functional tests) should be run frequently against parts of the application that are critical and volatile, at the same time. In other words, unit tests should not be written for the sake of writing tests, but rather to ensure tha the development/maintenance engineers do not trip over certain conditions in code.

That said, you might also want to take a look at integration tests that run in a CI server, more so because they're closer to the functional tests, and also because the code is mature. From my observations, identifying unit tests to write in a mature application is far difficult and has lesser RoI in the shorter term than integration tests.

Integration tests in your case will ensure that the various tiers of the application continue to be held together with the intentions of the original developers. Unit tests on the other hand, being a bit more localized in nature will ensure that any new patch/bug fix in a particular area does cause side effects in that location.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a massive effort and returns would be small. Rather automate and expand your current testing to ensure system stability (I assume there is some testing at system level). I think you should focus on parts of the system that still see lots of change or that you plan on changing in the near future.

Unit testing is good but can be difficult to retrofit into an existing system. If you just focus on unit testing for the next year or more you are going to lose forward momentum.

Answer (score 0):

I would not write tests just to write tests.  What would be the business payoff?  Your business has likely already suffered the effects of not having unit tests and now the issues have been addressed.  If I did add tests, I would only add them to the sections of code that would cause the most unpleasant results.  For example, I'd consider adding testing to any role/security related code.

Answer (score 0):

The situation which the O.P. has described is majorly a "mindset change" problem. In today's times, forcing your team-mates to adopt a particular habit doesn't work. You need to seed true motivation both in developers and in business stakeholders to make it a natural adoption. My suggestions:

1. Lead By Example: This is from real-life experience where I was leading a small sub-team of developers who were working on a big module which had to be delivered in 6-months and there was another sub-team on a similar task (different module). We decided to adopt automation testing practice (unit testing, API testing  etc.) with full zeal against the normal practice prevalent in other teams. I could see the difference when various modules were going through quality cycles before the final launch. Our module, due to robust test coverage, leaked very few defects against other modules developed for launch. Result, the business stakeholders and delivery managers were impressed and asked what did we do differently which led to better quality. For the team, we had free time on our hands before the launch against other sub-teams who were toiling day and night to get to the finish line. Next release onwards, we adopted many of the practices across sub-teams in the same program and natural adoption as a test strategy.
2. For a legacy application, ensure every bug you leak to quality, release or production environment also gets unit test coverage for the fix the team makes. This way you will add unit test cases to where they matter the most.
3. For new development, always write unit test cases to cover new stories.
4. Use your source control software to find out which area of your code base is changing more frequently than others. These area may become the focus of bringing them under unit test coverage.