# What resources can I use to convince the management to adopt unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

So where i work .. they are still not doing any unit testing. I need some good articles to present management the importance of unit testing.

Has anyone has good resources which I can use to present it to management?

Looking for some article written by some gurus so I can pass along making my suggestion to management more creditable.

Thanks,

Comment: I think this is off-topic here but on-topic on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) - in fact, it's a dupe of [this question on that site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78478/how-to-explain-the-value-of-unit-testing)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to find real articles written by someone "known". So looking for a reliable article on the subject so I can pass along management.

Comment: the [question referred](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78478/how-to-explain-the-value-of-unit-testing) to by @razlebe above [has an answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78478/how-to-explain-the-value-of-unit-testing/78482#78482) with links to articles by Robert C Martin and Martin Fowler. You can't get more "guru" than those guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this question which has nearly 200 upvotes:

[Is Unit Testing worth the effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299/is-unit-testing-worth-the-effort)

You might find some other helpful questions by clicking on the unit-testing tag.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some "creditable" articles to pass to management :) I'm not sure how they would take stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Some  guy asked this same question in a workshop i attended recently and i was this with my teammates in the morning and they all agreed that management should not be even bothered about this. Its part of your code. You write unit-test to increase your efficiency and facilitate latter refractoring of the code. Why should you even ask management whether you should write tests or not. They will just be interested in the final outcome.Its upto you whichever way you implement , using TDD or not.

Comment: I'd love to do that but reality is I can't just take decision like that knowing it affects your work load. Coming up with a testing infrastructure is not so trivial too. It takes time and you have to justify that time.