# Does TDD preclude designing first?

Tags: tdd

I've been reading about TDD lately, and it is advocated because it supposedly results in code that is more testable and less coupled (and a bunch of other reasons).

I haven't been able to find much in the way of practical examples, except for a [Roman numeral conversion](http://securesoftwaredev.com/2011/12/05/practicing-tdd-using-the-roman-numerals-kata/) and a [number-to-English converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18181/Test-Driven-First-Development-by-Example).

Observing these two examples, I observed the typical red-green-refactor cycles typical of TDD, as well as the application of the [rules of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd). However, this seemed like a big waste of time when normally I would observe a pattern and implement it in code, and then write tests for it after. Or possibly write a stub for the code, write the unit tests, and then write the implementation - which might arguably be TDD - but not this continuous case-by-case refactoring.

TDD appears to incite developers to jump right into the code and build their implementation inductively rather than designing a proper architecture. My opinion so far is that the benefits of TDD can be achieved by a proper architectural design, although admittedly not everyone can do this reasonably well.

So here I have two questions:

1. Am I right in understanding that using TDD pretty much doesn't allow you to design first (see the rules of TDD)?
2. Is there anything that TDD gives you that you can't get from doing proper design before you start coding?

Answer (score 0):

well, I was in your shoes some time ago and had the same questions. Since then I have done quite some reading about TDD and decided to mess with it a little.

I can summarize my experience about TDD in these points:

1. TDD is unit testing done right, ATDD/BDD is TDD done right.
2. Whether you design beforehand or not is totally up to you. Just make sure you don't do [BDUF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Design_Up_Front). Believe me you will end up changing most of it midways because you can never fully understand the requirements until your hands get dirty.
   OTOH, you can do enough design to get you started. Class diagrams, sequence diagrams, domain models, actors and collaborators are perfectly fine as long as you don't get hung up in the design phase trying to figure everything out.
   Some people don't do any design at all. They just let the code talk and concentrate on refactoring.
   IMHO, balance your approach. Do some design till you get the hang of it then start testing. When you reach a dead end then go back to the white board.
   One more thing, some things can't be solved by TDD like [figuring out an algorithm](http://vladimirlevin.blogspot.com/2007/04/tdd-is-not-algorithm-generator.html). This is a very interesting post that shows that some things just need to be designed first.
3. Unit testing is hard when you have the code already. TDD forces you to think from your API users perspective. This way you can early on decide if the public interface from your API is usable or not. If you decide to do unit testing after implementing everything you will find it tedious and most probably it will be only for some cases and I know some people who will right only passing test cases just to get the feature done. I mean who wants to break his own code after all that work?
   TDD breaks this mentality. Tests are first class citizens. You aren't allowed to skip tests. You aren't allowed to postpone some tests till the next release because we don't have enough time.
4. Finally to answer your question if there anything that TDD gives you that you can't get from doing proper design before you start coding, I would say commitment.
   As long as your doing TDD you are committed to apply good OO principles, so that your code is testable.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Personally I think commitment should come from the individual, not be enforced by some methodology, so I can't justify TDD just for that reason. Same goes for forcing API consumption - ensuring a usable API should be part of the design IMO. I can buy TDD in the sense that I explained (stub, test, implementation), but not in the strict sense according to the rules and as per the examples I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. "Test Driven Development" (TDD) is often referred to as "Test Driven Design", in that this practice will result in a good design of the code. When you have written a failing unit test, you are forced into a test driven *design* approach, so that you can implement just what is needed to make the test pass i.e. you have to consider the design of the code you are writing to make the test pass.
2. When using a TDD approach a developer will implement the minimum amount of code required to pass the test. Doing proper design beforehand usually results in waste if the requirements change once the project has started.

You say "TDD appears to incite developers to jump right into the code and build their implementation inductively rather than designing a proper architecture" - If you are following an Agile approach to your software development, then you do still need to do some up front architectural investigation (e.g. if you were using the Scrum methodology you would create a development "Spike" at the start of a project) to ascertain what the minimum amount of architecture needed to start the project. At this stage you make decisions based on what you know now e.g. if you had to work with a small dataset you'd choose to use a regular DB, if you have a huge DB you might to choose to use a NoSQL big data DB etc.

However, once you have a general idea of the architecture, you should let the design evolve as the project progresses leaving further architectural decisions as late in the process as possible; Invariably as a project progresses the architecture and requirements will change.

Further more this rather popular [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67299/203371) on SO will give you even more reasons why TDD is definetly worth the effort.

Comment: 1. I keep reading that TDD results in good design, but I have never seen a practical example to support this claim. 2. I think TDD results in bigger waste - if the requirements change, you have to change both the code AND the tests. Deferring writing tests until you have a solid code base avoids having to maintain both in parallel while you're still working things out.

Comment: @Gigi How often do you write unit tests? coz I think you are trying to learn TDD before experiencing the horror of testing legacy applications :D

Comment: Well, I don't use them all the time, but I have used them occasionally over the past 2 years. I'm trying to learn TDD as the next step.