# How to raise 503 error in django?

Tags: django, http-status-code-503, django-middleware

I want to make site maintenance page and I create singleton model for site maintenance with checkbox field, So when I checked that checkbox from Django admin then the site should show maintenance page if we hit any URL of the website.

I checked 503 status code is related to **SERVICE UNAVAILABLE** So 
How can I raise  503 error manually in my code and also want to render a custom template when 503 error raise.

Comment: It return 500 by default ? Or tell me what is the traceback, you can do an exception

Comment: No. I want to write code that will manually raise 503

Comment: If you have an error you can do an excepción and raise any template you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.urls import resolve
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import SiteMaintenance



class SiteMaintenanceMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def check_maintenance(self):
        site_maintenance = SiteMaintenance.get_object()
        return site_maintenance.is_maintenance

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if self.check_maintenance() and not request.user.is_staff:
            return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string('503.html'), status=503)
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors and responses can be found in [`django.http`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py).

As you can see, there is no exact match for a "service unavailable".

There are multiple ways of doing this using [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#middleware).

You could:
[Raise an custom exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python) when [the view is processed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) (you could call it `PageInMaintenanceException`).
Then [process your exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) returning a rendered template with the right header.

Or simply:
Return a rendered template with the right header when [the view is processed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) and the site set under maintenance is called.

Comment: I did not understand your way. Can you add example code of raise 503 in middleware?

Comment: I added a link to how to raise a custom exception. I need more information about your setup for more specific code: Are you using the [Django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites)? When your site is under maintenance, are you going to edit content only or will you be changing code (and therefore shut down the instance(s) running your website)? How does your "singleton model for site maintenance" look like?

Answer (score 0):

To raise a 503 from a view ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24660486/34935)):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    # Return an "Internal Server Error" 503 response code.
    return HttpResponse(status=503)
```

To set a custom 500 template ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725091/34935), [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view)):

```
def handler500(request, template_name="500.html"):
    response = render_to_response(template_name, {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 503
    return response
```

I have not yet thought through how to resolve the difference between 500 and 503.  Perhaps [session variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/)?

Still, I thought I'd post this to get a start on the answer.